# Can not find IP address from other network (iis)

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I'm attempting to create a server using IIS. 
I created a site. Configured the firewall. It's available in the browser as localhost(http://localhost:8555/) and static IP(http://10.12.66.79:8555/) too
But from another network like my phone. I tried accessing using the static IP but it failed. then I tried using the virtual IP then it show me the login page of my service provider.
what I can do next?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you grab a computer networking book some time to study the basic concepts.

10.*.*.* is a private address your ISP gives to your server,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses

So that this server can be accessed by other devices on the same network.

Your phone is on another network (via Internet in most cases), so it won't be able to access your server.

To pass packets between two networks, many other devices and settings are required.

If you do want to do experiments, public cloud computing platforms are far better an option, as they can give your server public IP addresses that can be accessed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the mobile's default DNS to your system's(IIS) IP may be this could help you but it can be able to run locally only. Make sure that your site is working in your system through the static IP (http://10.12.66.79:8555/) if it is working properly then this could be the only problem change the DNS.